# Elegantly convert DateTime type to a string formatted "dd-mmm"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have the following solution:

```
select 
  substring(convert(varchar(20),convert(datetime,getdate())),5,2)
  + ' ' +
  left(convert(varchar(20),convert(datetime,getdate())),3)
```

What is the elegant way of achieving this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dateName` function:

```
select right(N'0' + dateName(DD, getDate()), 2) + N'-' + dateName(M, getDate())
```

If you really want the `mmm` part to only have the tree-letter abbreviation of the month, you're stuck with parsing the appropriate conversion type, for example

```
select left(convert(nvarchar, getDate(), 7), 3)
```

The problem is that `dateName` doesn't have an option to get you the abbreviated month, and the abbreviation isn't always just the first three letters (for example, in czech, two months start with `Čer`). On the other hand, convert `7` always starts with the abbreviation. Now, even with this, I assume that the abbreviation is always three letters long, so it isn't necessarily 100% reliable (you could search for space instead), but I'm not aware of any better option in MS SQL.

Comment: you have a typo next to getdate

Comment: this option does not handle leading zeroes for single digit days, and he only wants the first 3 characters of month.

Comment: Also to get the 'mmm' part, make it `left(dateName(M, getdate()),3)`

Comment: @Knightwisp Yeah, I didn't catch that; `mmm` means milliseconds in MS SQL and minutes in .NET, so I wasn't quite sure what he means :) However, your solution doesn't work either, sadly. It may work in english, but english isn't the only language in the world :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
declare @date as date = getdate() 
select replace(convert(varchar(6), @date, 6), ' ', '-')

-- returns '11-Apr'
```

Format 6 is `dd mon yy` and you take the first 6 characters by converting to varchar(6). You just need to replace space with dash at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 6), 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t datetime = getdate()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),LEFT(@t,6),113)
```